# Is there a faster way to download font in vuejs?

Tags: css, vue.js

**GOAL**: faster download speed (under 1000ms)

**SITUATION**:I use VUEJS, use style scoped tag. all my result push to github, then heroku will hosting my webpage. So I access to my page, and check the content download speed. font download duration spend 21000ms. it's too slow.

I got AppleSDGothicNeo ttf font file.

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'AppleSdGothicNeoBold';
font-style: bold;
font-weight:700;
src: url('./assets/font/AppleSDGothicNeoB.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

on App.vue file.
and use css scoped tag.

```
.item {
       font-family: AppleSdGothicNeoBold;
}
.item2 {
       font-family:gmarcketsans;
}
```

and other items use same way like

home.vue ->

```
@font-face{ blah blah } 
.item1{ font-family: blah}
```

game.vue ->

```
 @font-face{ blah blah } 
.item1{ font-family: blah}
```

in the localhost, download speed reduce until 4s~6s. but in the heroku hosting, download speed is too slow.(21s~).

**I TRIED**: I heard ttf file is big. so I change my ttf file to woff file. woff file is lighter than ttf file, still download speed too slow. it is not fatal factor.(I think).

I am sure that there is more clever way than my method. Can i get a little help?

Comment: 21 seconds is a looooong time. Are you sure it's the font, and not [heroku](https://dev.to/elijahtrillionz/your-heroku-app-is-slow-to-load-because-of-this-4lep) itself?

Comment: What is the size of the font file?

Comment: I dont think 21s is explainable by the use of any of your code. In other words, it has something to do with the network or a really really big file (which is weird for a font).

Comment: @권동규 Can you share a link to this site that exhibits the problem?

Comment: http://company.gmarket.co.kr/company/about/company/company--font.asp this is my font which is 2.4MB size.

Comment: http://boardgamehaja.herokuapp.com/ this is site